# Using more than one argument for separate outputs for each one in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a script that looks for local packages in the system that I called *querypac*. It's very simple, just because I hate typing `yay -Q|grep foo`to look for these packages. It goes like:

```
#!/bin/zsh

echo "Search for: "; 
read package;
echo -----------------------------; 
yay -Q | grep "$package";  
echo -----------------------------
```

The problem is that it only supports one name. If I search for gimp, the output is like

```
--------------------------
gimp 2.10.14
--------------------------
```

What I want is to search like "gimp,vim" and have this:

```
---------------------------
gimp 2.10.14
---------------------------
---------------------------
gvim 8.1.226B-2
---------------------------
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use **egrep** with pipe "|" to search for multiple keywords.

**Example:**

```
bash-3.2$ cat packages.txt
gimp 2.10.14
gmaps
gvim 8.1.226B-2
Goodtogo
Someotherpackagevim 10.000

bash-3.2$ egrep -i "gimp|gvim" packages.txt
gimp 2.10.14
gvim 8.1.226B-2
bash-3.2$
```

Assuming in this case input is given as 'gimp|gvim'

```
package='gimp|gvim'
yay -Q | egrep "${package}"
```

If the input is be passes with spaces then a for loop would help to achieve this.

**Code:**

```
echo "Search for: ";
read package;

for srch in $package
do
echo "-----------------------------"
yay -Q | grep "$srch"
echo "-----------------------------"
done
```

**Example of input:** Give input as below

```
Search for: 
gvim gcam
```

The output will be as expected.